# Automatically format Time, monetary values and phone numbers in Outlook

Tags: regex, vba, outlook, wildcard

Is there a way that upon typing a time of day such as 10:24 am/pm, or any monetary value or phone number that it will automatically format the text? Would I need a regular expression or wildcards? And how would I make that work with both ActiveExplorer and ActiveInspector?

Right now I have something like the below but it's only working as a pop out

```
Sub ReplaceWithBoldHTML2()
    Dim regExp As Object
    Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim item As Object
    Set item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    
    If TypeOf item Is Outlook.mailItem Then
        Dim bodyHTML As String
        bodyHTML = item.htmlBody
    
        ' Find the position of the signature
        Dim signaturePos As Long
        signaturePos = InStr(1, bodyHTML, "Best,")

        ' Check if the signature is found
        If signaturePos > 0 Then
            ' Extract the portion of the body above the signature
            Dim bodyAboveSignature As String
            bodyAboveSignature = Left(bodyHTML, signaturePos - 1)
            
            ' Apply the regex pattern to the extracted portion
            With regExp
                .pattern = "\$[0-9]{1,3}(([\.?,?][0-9]{1,3}){1,})?"
                .Global = True
                
                ' Iterate through each match in the HTML body above the signature
                For Each match In .Execute(bodyAboveSignature)
                    ' Replace each match with a bold version
                    bodyAboveSignature = Replace(bodyAboveSignature, match.Value, "<b>" & match.Value & "</b>")
                Next match
            End With
            
            ' Update the HTMLBody property with the modified HTML
            item.htmlBody = bodyAboveSignature & Mid(bodyHTML, signaturePos)
        Else
            MsgBox "Signature not found.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "This code is designed for MailItems in Outlook.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which language is this? Some sort of VBA?

Comment: @tripleee, that is _[Microsoft's Visual Basic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)_.  Arguably, one of the best programming languages.

Comment: `Replace` only supports literal text replacement. Use `Regexp` library.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to create a code that somewhat works. However, I ran into a new problem. Here are a few of them:

1. I have the macro called through ThisOutlookSession via a private sub. Whenever the email is in folder view and I press "send", the macro is called but it brings it into a pop out window. So I run the code again and it does the formatting. When playing around with this I made the private sub in ThisOutlookSession call the macro twice so since I didn't understand what to do.
2. Sometimes Microsoft Outlook doesn't recognize the signature "Best". Once that message pops up, the email will send but Outlook will crash. This may be due to the fact that if I have the email in a pop out window and it runs twice but I'm not quite sure.
3. For some reason when I add the this regular expression to the .pattern '[0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{1,2}([/-][0-9]{2,4})?' it will add random code to the top of the code such as **04/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">** or something similar every single time. None of my other Regex's do this.

EDIT: It looks like all expressions are now causing that problem and I don't know why.

Below is the code:

```
Sub BoldDarkBlueValues()
    Dim regExp As Object
    Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim Item As Object
    Dim bodyHTML As String
    Dim signaturePos As Long
    Dim bodyAboveSignature As String

    ' Check if the active window is an Explorer or an Inspector
    If TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow) = "Explorer" Then
        ' For Explorer, work with the selected items
        Set Item = ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1)
        
        ' Get the Inspector associated with the selected item
        Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
        Set insp = Item.GetInspector
        ' Activate the Inspector to ensure it's fully loaded
        insp.Activate
    ElseIf TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
        ' For Inspector, work with the currently open item
        Set Item = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        MsgBox "Unsupported window type.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailItem Then
        ' Get the HTML body of the email
        bodyHTML = Item.htmlBody

        ' Find the position of the signature
        signaturePos = InStr(1, bodyHTML, "Best,")

        ' Check if the signature is found
        If signaturePos > 0 Then
            ' Extract the portion of the body above the signature
            bodyAboveSignature = Left(bodyHTML, signaturePos - 1)

            ' Apply the regex pattern to the extracted portion
            With regExp
                .pattern = "(\$[0-9]{1,3}(([\.?,?][0-9]{1,3}){1,})?)|(\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4})|(\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:\s?[AaPp](\.?)[Mm]\1)?)|([0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,2})?\%)"
                .Global = True

                ' Iterate through each match in the HTML body above the signature
                For Each match In .Execute(bodyAboveSignature)
                    ' Replace each match with a bold version
                    bodyAboveSignature = Replace(bodyAboveSignature, match.Value, "<span style=""color: #081E36; font-weight: bold;"">" & match.Value & "</span>")
                Next match
            End With

            ' Update the HTMLBody property with the modified HTML
            Item.htmlBody = bodyAboveSignature & Mid(bodyHTML, signaturePos)
        Else
            MsgBox "Signature not found for some reason.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "This code is designed for MailItems in Outlook.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```